# probability density functions

Tags: probability

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable pdf $f(y)=ky , y=3/n,6/n,9/n...,3n/n$

1. Find the value of the constant $k$ and write down $Y$'s cdf.
2. Find simple general expressions for $EY, \text{Var} \,Y, P(Y=3/2)$ and $P(Y>3/2)$
3. For the case $n=10$, evaluate $EY, \text{Var}\,Y,P(Y=3/2)$ and $P(Y>3/2)$, then write down $Y$'s pdf and cdf.
4. Repeat (3) for the limiting case as $n$ tends to infinity.
   HINT: The random variable in (4) has cdf equal to the limit of the cdf (1) as $n\to \infty$.

Wondering if it's possible to consider $Y$'s cdf by cases, like when $y=3/n,y=6/n...$ and sum up to get the value of k.

Could anyone help? thanks.

Comment: I think $k=\dfrac{2}{3(n+1)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed. For the function $f$ to be a valid PDF one must have that $f(y)\geq 0$ for all possible $y$-values *and* that
$$
\sum_{y}f(y)=1\tag{1}
$$
where the sum is taken over the possible values of $y$. Note that the possible values $$\frac3n, \frac6n,\ldots,\frac{3n}n$$ are of the form 
$\frac{3i}{n},$ where $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, and hence $(1)$ becomes
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n k\frac{3i}{n}=1.
$$
Using that $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{(n+1)n}{2}$ we obtain that
$$
1=\frac{3k}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{3k}{n}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=k\frac32(n+1)
$$
exactly as proposed by @Argha.

---

To find the CDF of $Y$ we note that $P(Y=y)=f(y)=ky$ for $y=\frac{3i}{n}$ for some $i=1,\ldots,n$. The CDF is by definition given by
$$
F(y)=P(Y\leq y)=\sum_{y'\leq y}f(y')
$$
so you're simply summing $f(y')$ for the values $y'$ that are less than $y$. Hence $F(y)$ becomes a step function that jumps exactly at the values $\frac{3i}n$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: I did the same thing to find K, but how about Y's cdf?

Comment: @CLoud: See the edit.

Comment: For the second part of the question, I already worked out P(Y=3/2) What should I do with P(Y>3/2) as y=3i/n?

Comment: @CLoud: $P(Y>3/2)=1-P(Y\leq 3/2)$

Comment: How to find P(Y<=3/2)?

Comment: @CLoud: Please, you have just found the CDF, haven't you? And what is the definition of the CDF? I think you should give it a little time and do some thinking on your own instead of just asking for the solution right away.

Comment: As if n=5, y=3/5,6/5,.... in this case 3/5 and 6/5 is Y<= 3/2

Comment: @CLoud: No, as in: did you or did you not compute the CDF $F(y)$? If you did, then you're done.

Comment: @Stefan Hansen I have a question about this, it may sound basic but Im trying to understand the problem. Is the random variable Discrete or Continuous?

Comment: @Luna: It is discrete as it only takes on finitely many values.

Comment: @Stefan Hansen, Thanks for your response.. If its not continuous, im not too sure how to find P(Y<=3/2) as I would intergrate (0-3/2) it if was continuous. How would I go about finding it if its disctrete?

Comment: @Luna: When you're dealing with discrete variables you need to sum instead of integrating. For instance, $P(Y\leq \frac32)=\sum_{y\leq \frac32}P(Y=y)$. Now, what this expression is, of course depends on what $n$ is, right? For example, if $n=1$, then the sum is $0$. If $n=2$ the sum is $P(Y=\frac32)=k\cdot \frac32$. If $n=4$ the sum is $P(Y=\frac34)+P(Y=\frac64)$ and so on.

Comment: @Stefan Hansen, So for n=10 I would need to sum all the probabilities for y, when y = 3/2, 3/3, 3/4, 6/4, 3/5, 6/5, 3/6, 6/6, 9/6, ..., 15/10?

Comment: @Luna: If $n=10$, then the random variable takes on the values $\frac{3}{10}, \frac{6}{10},\ldots, \frac{30}{10}$ and in order to find $P(Y\leq \frac32)$ you have to sum $P(Y=y)$ for all $y$-values that are $\leq \frac32$. This would be $\frac{3}{10},\frac{6}{10},\frac{9}{10},\frac{12}{10},\frac{15}{10}$.

Comment: @Stefan Hansen, Okay I understand that now.. Thanks for your time Stefan. Oh, and am I right with the expecation, EY = sum(y*f(y))

Comment: @Luna: You have been posting several answers which the moderators have been converting into comments to this post.  This is practice is discouraged, and it would be much preferable to post your own question concerning this answer.  Or to gain [sufficient privileges](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) by to post comments to all posts.

Comment: @Luna: Yes, you're right.